# How to use two Li in html with different properties?

Tags: html, css

## Background

I am using `li` elements for multiple purposes in the same page. In one spot, I use them for a navbar, and later in the page I use them for an image grid.

## Problem

The problem is that in the navbar I have a drop down so when I hover over the drop down half of the portion of the drop down hides under the images.

[image]

## Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Babies And Bridal </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Custom.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>


    <style>
        .images{
            margin-left: 55px;
        }
        .menuu {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #FDF4F9;
            display: inline-block; 

        }
        .menuu a{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Hoefler Text;
            font-style: italic !important;
            color: #984807 !important; 
        }
        li {
            float: left;

        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #ECC6C4;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #FDF4F9;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ECC6C4;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <img src="images/logo.jpg" class = "logo">
    </br> </br>

    <h1> Sweet Brown Suga </h1>




<center>
    <table class = "icons">

        <tr>

            <td>
                <h2 align = "right" style = "margin-right: 70px "> Brown Suga On Social </h2>
            </td>

            <td width = "55">
                <img src = "icons/instagram.png" width = "50" height = "55">
            </td>

            <td width = "55">
                <img src = "icons/facebook.png" width = "50" height = "55">
            </td>

            <td width = "55">
                <img src = "icons/twitter.png" width = "50" height = "55">
            </td>

            <td width = "55">
                <img src = "icons/envelop.png" width = "50" height = "55">
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

</center>

<br/>
<br/>


<div class="outer">

    <img class = "image" src = "images/sprinkles.jpg">

    <img class = "image" src = "images/sprinkles.jpg">

    <img class = "image" src = "images/sprinkles.jpg">

    <img class = "image" src = "images/sprinkles2.jpg">

</div>




<center>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ul class="menuu">

        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Celebration.html">Celebration</a>
                <a href="Wedding.html">Wedding</a>
                <a href="#">Babies and Bridal</a>
                <a href="Sculpted_3D.html">Sculpted_3D</a>
                <a href="Dessert Table.html">Dessert Table</a>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</center>
<br/> 
<br/> 
<br/>
<br/> 


<ul class="clearing-thumbs images" data-clearing >
    <li><a  class="th"><img data-caption="The Pulpit Rock" src="1.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a  class="th"><img data-caption="Sunrise Skies" src="2.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a  class="th"><img data-caption="Northern Lights" src="4.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a  class="th"><img data-caption="Northern Lights" src="4.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a></li>
    <li><a  class="th"><img data-caption="Northern Lights" src="4.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a></li>


</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<!-- Initialize Foundation JS -->

<center>
    <footer>

        <br/>

        Copy &COPY; 2016 Sweet Brown Suga. All Rights Reserved. Designed by ShawBK.

    </footer>
</center>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).foundation();
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: @AndyM That's the main issue, please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a higher `z-index` value to the `.dropdown-content`:

```
.dropdown-content {
   ...
   z-index: 10;
}
```

P.S. please **avoid** the following:

- `<center>` tag
- `table` elements for layout
- space between HTML properties and values (`class = " image "` should be `class="image"`)
- internal CSS (you already have a `custom.css` file)